# Why do I need to create a dataframe just to add a column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

So I worked with a bit of pandas and in that, it's easy to add a column to an existing dataframe. But in spark, a new dataframe needs to be created using 'withColumn'. I'm a complete newbie so is there some function I'm missing to add new columns? Or is it that in actuality only one dataframe is created and the new ones just point back to the columns of the old dataframe with the addition of the new column?
I'm using pyspark btw.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: dataframes are immutable in Spark